# Kendo Grid Inline Edit with Drop Down option disabled

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid with inline edit options. I have a dropdown from which user have to select values. I want to disable certain items from the dropdown dynamically. I have to dynamically enable and disable options from dropdown so I store disabled objects in a separate array than source. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eQfh4/1/) is an example.

```
columns: [{
            field: "xxxx",
            title: "xxxx",
            template: function (dt) {
                return dt.xxxx;
            },
            editor: function (container, options) {
                $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField: "textField",
                        dataValueField: "ValueField",
                        dataDisabled:arrayOfObjThatShouldBeDisabled,//Don't work I know
                        dataSource: {
                            data: myDataSource // DYNAMIC SOURCE
                        }
                    });
            }
        }]
```

Here is a [sample](https://dojo.telerik.com/iNAJeK) from Kendo website.

[Another Example](http://jsbin.com/yozanimi/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: And what is your issue ? The dojo example does just what you want.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Thanks for comment but it just doesn't work. I have set id, and isDeleted options, it doesn't give any runtime error but didn't disabled the option

Comment: There is not enough source code of your problem. You should add more or even a dojo example. Otherwise will be hard to help.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Thank you for your help, after studying the code and give it time to understand, I realized it was using Html Templates which resides in the script `<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">` and the code was calling it from `template: kendo.template($("#template").html())` . I was confused with the `isDeleted` property but now its all crystal clear. Thanks again

Comment: @StackOfLove if you already got the solution please post it as an answer. It will help others if they come across the same issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question revolves closely to [this Kendo UI Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/iNAJeK) keeping it base I try to explain what the code is does and how it map to my problem.

First of all we need some kind of flag to identify where the option has to be disable or not for that introduce `isDeleted`flag with `false`, will update accordingly.

Then we need to add following section in html, here is where the magic happens it gives you a template which will decide either we have to add `k-state-disabled` class to option or not depending upon the value of `isDeleted`.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <span class="#: isDeleted ? 'k-state-disabled': ''#">
       #: name #
    </span>
</script>
```

With that I have to made minor changes to code as follows and it worked

```
$('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        dataSource: {
                        data: myDataSource // DYNAMIC SOURCE
                        },
                        dataTextField: "textField",
                        dataValueField: "ValueField",
                        select: function (e) {
                            if (e.dataItem.isDeleted) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                        },
                        template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
                    });
```